# What's the equivalent age of a Metis' homid-form after their First Change?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-the-apocalypse

With garou/fera, homid-born tend to have their First Change during adolescence or just after and the animal-born tend to have it as an adult.

So obviously, homid-born would appear the age they are and the animal-born would look like an adult when able to shift into a homid form: because that's what they are.

But, out of curiosity, with those who are *metis*: how old would they actually *look* with their homid form, after undergoing their First Change?

To use the garou as an example: this apparently happens when they are about 8.

Is there any official information on what the human equivalent of this age would be? As in the range of teen -> adult?

I have been able to find that metis certainly are children for a good while, full childhood periods being mentioned, but no more than that about their pre-change aging rates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 74 of the Werewolf 20th Anniversary book says:

> Lupus and metis reach maturity more quickly than homids. A metis hits
>   adolescence between eight and 10, and a lupus is usually full-grown
>   after just a year or two. However, all breeds age at the same rate
>   once they undergo their First Change.

I've taken "reach maturity" to mean that a metis would appear to be a human aged 16-20 when they undergo their first change: they appear to be fully, physically mature.

Also, they have a comparable emotional maturity - a metis isn't a 10-year-old in an 18-year-old's body.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the breed of a Garou always follows the mother in non-Metis situations, I would have to say that **the mother's breed determines the Metis apparent age**. Going by the W20 book I have, there is a sidebar on p74 stating that the physical age of a Metis at First Change is the same as Lupus (8-10) for chronology sake. With a Homid mother, the change would happen (apparent) age 10-16 as stated on p42.